# Is it possible to implement a form of namespacing in Java Enums?

Tags: java, enums

In the enum below I see three three distinct classes of messages that exist within the `Message` enum: `Form`, `Site` and `Admin`.

Is it possible to implement a type of `namespace` mechanism in an enum so that, instead of writing

```
Message.SITE_ERROR 
Message.ADMIN_ERROR
```

you write, this:

```
Message.Site.ERROR 
Message.Admin.ERROR
```

so that `Site` and `Admin` represent the "namespace" below which additional categories of messages can exist?

```
public enum Message {
    //FORM
    FORM_EMPTY("You've gotta put something in the form."),

    //SITE
    SITE_ERROR("Whoa. What happened?"),
    SITE_ALERT("Hey, it's that time again.");

    //ADMIN
    ADMIN_ERROR("Gotta look into this, dude."),
    ADMIN_ALERT("Time to get the lead out.");


    private String messageString;
    private Message(String messageString){
        this.messageString=messageString;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { 
        return messageString; 
    }   
}
```

Comment: Maybe just make three separate `enum` types, but have them implement a common interface.

Answer (score 0):

You could use packages?

for example:

```
com.foo.messages
```

is your base package. Then you can expand from that

```
com.foo.messages.site
com.foo.messages.admin
```

Et cetera...

Answer (score 0):

You could make `Message` an interface that declares enums `Site` and `Admin`. But then, of course, you can't pass around a `Message` object and expect an enum, just a `Message.<something>` object.

What do you want this for?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, just use inner classes.

```
public interface State {
    String getMessageString();
}

public class Message {

    public static enum Form implements State {    
        EMPTY("You've gotta put something in the form."),

        private final String msg;
        public Form(String msg) { this.msg = msg; }
        public String getMessageString() { return msg; }
    }

    public static enum Site implements State {
        ERROR("Whoa. What happened?"),
        ALERT("Hey, it's that time again.");

        private final String msg;
        public Site(String msg) { this.msg = msg; }
        public String getMessageString() { return msg; }
    }

    public static enum Admin implements State {
        ADMIN_ERROR("Gotta look into this, dude."),
        ADMIN_ALERT("Time to get the lead out.");

        private final String msg;
        public Admin(String msg) { this.msg = msg; }
        public String getMessageString() { return msg; }
    }
}
```

I think you may get rid of the repeated code with a common base class but my memory is fuzzy on extending enums so that may not work...

Comment: This could work, but I'd hate to see how you would manage it if every enum got 100+ entries =)